# Chrome beta keeps forgetting default BitTorrent for magnet links

Tags: google-chrome, bittorrent, vuze

It was working on Chrome. I installed Chrome Beta. On Chrome Beta, it keeps asking if Vuze (my BitTorrent client) should be used to open the magnet link despite clicking the checkbox. I uninstalled Chrome after.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the internal Chrome page for protocol/handlers

chrome://settings/handlers

Comment: It only has 1 option there? ‘Allow sites to ask to become default handlers for protocols (recommended)’.

Comment: In which case, are you using Windows or Mac? It's using your defaults so you'll need to change it in your OS settings, Windows I believe is in Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Select defaults by app.macOS I can't remember but I'm sure you'll find it in the System Preferences panel

Comment: Windows. Vuze was made the default but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue and solved it by simply following these steps

1. Go to Chrome's user data directory. On Windows, that would be in the following path:

   `C:\Users\`**`[YOUR USER NAME]`**`\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
2. Open the file **Preferences** with a text-editor, e.g. Notepad or Notepad++.
3. Search for the following line or chunk of text:

   `"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{}}`
4. Replace it with the following string:

   `"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"magnet":false}}`

Please note, if Chrome is running, some text-editor will prompt you to "reload the changed file". Don't do that, since it will reset the file to the version the browser knows it.

Instead, when done, it is a good idea to close your browser and *then* save the file.